# Is there a mistake in the convergence proof in Watkins technical note of Q-learning?

Tags: probability, inequality

I am reading the technical note about Q-learning written by Christopher J.C.H Watkins[(Watkins, 1992)](https://www.gatsby.ucl.ac.uk/%7Edayan/papers/cjch.pdf). The proof of Theorem B.4 quite confuses me.

The author assumes that $|\mathcal R_x^i(a) - \mathcal R_x(a)| < \eta$ and $|P^i_{xy}[a] - P_{xy}[a]| < \frac{\eta}{\mathcal R}, \forall a, i, x, y$, where $\mathcal R_x(a)$ and $\mathcal R_x^i(a)$ are the mean rewards given state $x$ and action $a$, $P_{xy}[a]$ and $P^i_{xy}[a]$ are transition probabilities from state $x$ to state $y$ when action $a$ is taken. $\mathcal R_x(a)$ and $P_{xy}[a]$ are from real process, while $\mathcal R_x^i(a)$ and $P^i_{xy}[a]$ are from a simulative process. Both  $\mathcal R_x(a)$ and $\mathcal R_x^i(a)$ are bounded by $\mathcal R$, which means that $|\mathcal R_x(a)| < \mathcal R$ and $|\mathcal R_x^i(a)| < \mathcal R$. $\eta > 0$ is a constant value.

Given conditions above, the author gives an inequation in proof of Theorem B.4:
$$|\mathcal R_x^1(a_1) - \mathcal R_x(a_1)| + \gamma|\sum_y P^1_{xy}[a_2](\mathcal R^2_y(a_2) - \mathcal R_y(a_2))| + \gamma |\sum_y (P^1_{xy}[a_2] - P_{xy}[a_2])\mathcal R_y(a_2)| < 3\eta$$
where $\gamma$ is a factor satisfying $0 < \gamma < 1$. The origin inequation in the paper seems to have some typos. So I made some modification in the equation above. Here is the origin version:
$$|\mathcal R_x^1(a_1) - \mathcal R_x(a_1)| + \gamma|\sum_y P^2_{xy}[a_2](\mathcal R^2_y(a_2) - \mathcal R_x(a_2))| + \gamma |\sum_y (P^2_{xy}[a_2] - P_{xy}[a_2])\mathcal R_x(a_2)| < 3\eta.$$

However, no matter in which version, I think the 3rd item in the left side of the inequation should be like:
$$\begin{aligned}\gamma |\sum_y (P^1_{xy}[a_2] - P_{xy}[a_2])\mathcal R_y(a_2)| &< \sum_y |(P^1_{xy}[a_2] - P_{xy}[a_2])\mathcal R_y(a_2)|\\&=\sum_y |(P^1_{xy}[a_2] - P_{xy}[a_2])||\mathcal R_y(a_2)|\\&<\sum_y \frac{\eta}{\mathcal R}|\mathcal R_y(a_2)|\\&<\eta|S|\end{aligned}$$
where $S$ is the state space of the real process, i.e., $x \in S$ and $y \in S$. Therefore, I think the right side of the inequation should be $\eta(2 + |S|)$.

Am I wrong? Or is this really a mistake made by the author?

Comment: I'm studying Watkins & Dayan's paper too, can you share the bibliography that helped you along your studies?